# txt file to binary tree in python

Tags: python, text, tree, binary

I have received a text file as part of a task that contains 2^n-1 characters (suitable for a perfect binary tree with height n) and I'm supposed to represent that text as a binary tree. Is there a proper way to do it? A certain order? 
Thank you in advance and sorry for the weird question.

Comment: A tree represents parent-child relations between its nodes. You did not specify which characters relate to which others as parents and children. What is the purpose of this tree?

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I understand your point, that is the reason I was seaking for advice, it is not mentioned at all. My initial thought was that maybe each character is represented by its index, and it is supposed to be a tree of numbers. Is that a possibilty?

Comment: who's to say? Is there some specific algorithm that you would be required to run on that tree? Otherwise, you can just call it a tree, and be done with it.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron I am given pairs of numbers and I believe they want me to find their lowest common ancestor (Tarjan's algorithm).

Comment: So the file contains 2^n-1 numbers, right? And they are unique? If that is the case, please edit your question to reflect these facts.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron The file contains 2^n-1 random ascii characters. I'm just assuming, that I'm supposed to give each character a number myself. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Are the characters unique? How are the characters passed over to the program? By character, by its position in the file? Your presentation is very confusing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213574/discussion-between-ron-libman-and-amitai-irron).